# How can I convert to data from filenames in a list?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply, lubridate

I have a list of filenames `dat`:

```
 [1] "d_t_2016-12-11-00_H1.nc"
 [2] "d_t_2016-12-12-00_H1.nc"
 [3] "d_t_2016-12-13-00_H1.nc"
```

I can extract the time using the following (`lubridate` library)

```
fdate <- as.Date(strsplit(dat[1], "_")[[1]][3], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

But how can I do this using `lapply`? open to other solutions too.

```
lapply(dat, function(x) as.Date(strsplit(x, "_")[[1]][3], "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Currently, I get `NULL` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `lapply`:

```
dat <- c("d_t_2016-12-11-00_H1.nc", "d_t_2016-12-12-00_H1.nc", "d_t_2016-12-13-00_H1.nc")

lapply(strsplit(dat, "_"), function(x) as.Date(x[3], '%Y-%m-%d-%H'))

#[[1]]
#[1] "2016-12-11"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2016-12-12"

#[[3]]
#[1] "2016-12-13"
```

---

You can also use `data.table::tstrsplit`:

```
as.Date(tstrsplit(dat, "_")[[3]], '%Y-%m-%d-%H')
# [1] "2016-12-11" "2016-12-12" "2016-12-13"
```

Answer (score 1):

And another solution with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
as.Date(str_extract(dat, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

However, your original lapply seems to work for the list entries you have posted; is it possible that some of the files have a different format?